# external monitor vga port with internal intel graphic not working with ubuntu 20.04 wayland

Tags: 20.04, wayland

I'm using ubuntu desktop for about 12 years Using the LTS released.
and using External monitor (Acer G195HOV) vga port connected to my laptop hp2540p.
It's working good within ubuntu desktop 16.04 LTS,
and "working for a while" after upgrade to ubuntu 20.04 LTS.
After the kernel updated to version 5.10 the external monitor stop working.... Blank screen.

FYI:
Currently I'm using ubuntu 20.04 with kernel 5.15.

```
jerry@hp-2540p:~$ hostnamectl
   Static hostname: hp-2540p
         Icon name: computer-laptop
           Chassis: laptop
        Machine ID: de4b56ef6180e8fc7e641c9d5fddb479
           Boot ID: fb02c732e3cf4de2bd716259ecfdee56
  Operating System: Ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS
            Kernel: Linux 5.15.0-17-generic
      Architecture: x86-64

jerry@hp-2540p:~$ echo $XDG_SESSION_TYPE
wayland

jerry@hp-2540p:~$ sudo lspci -v
[sudo] password for jerry:
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Core Processor DRAM Controller (rev 02)
 Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Core Processor DRAM Controller
 Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0
 Capabilities: [e0] Vendor Specific Information: Len=0c <?>

00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Core Processor Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 02) (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])
 DeviceName: 32
 Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Core Processor Integrated Graphics Controller
 Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 29
 Memory at d0000000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=4M]
 Memory at c0000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=256M]
 I/O ports at 5058 [size=8]
 Expansion ROM at 000c0000 [virtual] [disabled] [size=128K]
 Capabilities: [90] MSI: Enable+ Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit-
 Capabilities: [d0] Power Management version 2
 Capabilities: [a4] PCI Advanced Features
 Kernel driver in use: i915
 Kernel modules: i915

00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset HECI Controller (rev 06)
 Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset HECI Controller
 Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 30
 Memory at d4724000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16]
 Capabilities: [50] Power Management version 3
 Capabilities: [8c] MSI: Enable+ Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit+
 Kernel driver in use: mei_me
 Kernel modules: mei_me

00:16.3 Serial controller: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset KT Controller (rev 06) (prog-if 02 [16550])
 Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset KT Controller
 Flags: bus master, 66MHz, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 17
 I/O ports at 5050 [size=8]
 Memory at d472b000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=4K]
 Capabilities: [c8] Power Management version 3
 Capabilities: [d0] MSI: Enable- Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit+
 Kernel driver in use: serial

00:19.0 Ethernet controller: Intel Corporation 82577LM Gigabit Network Connection (rev 05)
 Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company 82577LM Gigabit Network Connection
 Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 27
 Memory at d4700000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=128K]
 Memory at d472a000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=4K]
 I/O ports at 5020 [size=32]
 Capabilities: [c8] Power Management version 2
 Capabilities: [d0] MSI: Enable+ Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit+
 Capabilities: [e0] PCI Advanced Features
 Kernel driver in use: e1000e
 Kernel modules: e1000e

00:1a.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset USB2 Enhanced Host Controller (rev 05) (prog-if 20 [EHCI])
 Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset USB2 Enhanced Host Controller
 Flags: bus master, medium devsel, latency 0, IRQ 16
 Memory at d4729000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=1K]
 Capabilities: [50] Power Management version 2
 Capabilities: [58] Debug port: BAR=1 offset=00a0
 Capabilities: [98] PCI Advanced Features
 Kernel driver in use: ehci-pci

00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset High Definition Audio (rev 05)
 Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset High Definition Audio
 Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 32
 Memory at d4720000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
 Capabilities: [50] Power Management version 2
 Capabilities: [60] MSI: Enable+ Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit+
 Capabilities: [70] Express Root Complex Integrated Endpoint, MSI 00
 Capabilities: [100] Virtual Channel
 Capabilities: [130] Root Complex Link
 Kernel driver in use: snd_hda_intel
 Kernel modules: snd_hda_intel

00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset PCI Express Root Port 1 (rev 05) (prog-if 00 [Normal decode])
 Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 24
 Bus: primary=00, secondary=01, subordinate=01, sec-latency=0
 I/O behind bridge: [disabled]
 Memory behind bridge: d4600000-d46fffff [size=1M]
 Prefetchable memory behind bridge: [disabled]
 Capabilities: [40] Express Root Port (Slot+), MSI 00
 Capabilities: [80] MSI: Enable+ Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit-
 Capabilities: [90] Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset PCI Express Root Port 1
 Capabilities: [a0] Power Management version 2
 Kernel driver in use: pcieport

00:1c.1 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset PCI Express Root Port 2 (rev 05) (prog-if 00 [Normal decode])
 Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 25
 Bus: primary=00, secondary=02, subordinate=42, sec-latency=0
 I/O behind bridge: 00003000-00004fff [size=8K]
 Memory behind bridge: d0600000-d45fffff [size=64M]
 Prefetchable memory behind bridge: 00000000d4900000-00000000d4afffff [size=2M]
 Capabilities: [40] Express Root Port (Slot+), MSI 00
 Capabilities: [80] MSI: Enable+ Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit-
 Capabilities: [90] Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset PCI Express Root Port 2
 Capabilities: [a0] Power Management version 2
 Kernel driver in use: pcieport

00:1c.3 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset PCI Express Root Port 4 (rev 05) (prog-if 00 [Normal decode])
 Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 26
 Bus: primary=00, secondary=43, subordinate=43, sec-latency=0
 I/O behind bridge: [disabled]
 Memory behind bridge: d0500000-d05fffff [size=1M]
 Prefetchable memory behind bridge: [disabled]
 Capabilities: [40] Express Root Port (Slot+), MSI 00
 Capabilities: [80] MSI: Enable+ Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit-
 Capabilities: [90] Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset PCI Express Root Port 4
 Capabilities: [a0] Power Management version 2
 Kernel driver in use: pcieport

00:1d.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset USB2 Enhanced Host Controller (rev 05) (prog-if 20 [EHCI])
 Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset USB2 Enhanced Host Controller
 Flags: bus master, medium devsel, latency 0, IRQ 20
 Memory at d4728000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=1K]
 Capabilities: [50] Power Management version 2
 Capabilities: [58] Debug port: BAR=1 offset=00a0
 Capabilities: [98] PCI Advanced Features
 Kernel driver in use: ehci-pci

00:1e.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 82801 Mobile PCI Bridge (rev a5) (prog-if 01 [Subtractive decode])
 Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0
 Bus: primary=00, secondary=44, subordinate=45, sec-latency=64
 I/O behind bridge: 00002000-00002fff [size=4K]
 Memory behind bridge: d0400000-d04fffff [size=1M]
 Prefetchable memory behind bridge: [disabled]
 Capabilities: [50] Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company 82801 Mobile PCI Bridge

00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation QM57 Chipset LPC Interface Controller (rev 05)
 Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company QM57 Chipset LPC Interface Controller
 Flags: bus master, medium devsel, latency 0
 Capabilities: [e0] Vendor Specific Information: Len=10 <?>
 Kernel driver in use: lpc_ich
 Kernel modules: lpc_ich

00:1f.2 SATA controller: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset 6 port SATA AHCI Controller (rev 05) (prog-if 01 [AHCI 1.0])
 Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset 6 port SATA AHCI Controller
 Flags: bus master, 66MHz, medium devsel, latency 0, IRQ 28
 I/O ports at 5048 [size=8]
 I/O ports at 5064 [size=4]
 I/O ports at 5040 [size=8]
 I/O ports at 5060 [size=4]
 I/O ports at 5000 [size=32]
 Memory at d4727000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=2K]
 Capabilities: [80] MSI: Enable+ Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit-
 Capabilities: [70] Power Management version 3
 Capabilities: [a8] SATA HBA v1.0
 Capabilities: [b0] PCI Advanced Features
 Kernel driver in use: ahci
 Kernel modules: ahci

00:1f.6 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset Thermal Subsystem (rev 05)
 Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset Thermal Subsystem
 Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 18
 Memory at d4726000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=4K]
 Capabilities: [50] Power Management version 3
 Capabilities: [80] MSI: Enable- Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit-
 Kernel driver in use: intel ips
 Kernel modules: intel_ips

43:00.0 Network controller: Intel Corporation Centrino Advanced-N 6200 (rev 35)
 DeviceName: WLAN
 Subsystem: Intel Corporation Centrino Advanced-N 6200 2x2 AGN
 Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 31
 Memory at d0500000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=8K]
 Capabilities: [c8] Power Management version 3
 Capabilities: [d0] MSI: Enable+ Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit+
 Capabilities: [e0] Express Endpoint, MSI 00
 Capabilities: [100] Advanced Error Reporting
 Capabilities: [140] Device Serial Number 00-23-14-ff-ff-7a-5e-f4
 Kernel driver in use: iwlwifi
 Kernel modules: iwlwifi

44:06.0 FireWire (IEEE 1394): Ricoh Co Ltd R5C832 IEEE 1394 Controller (rev 06) (prog-if 10 [OHCI])
 Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company R5C832 IEEE 1394 Controller
 Flags: bus master, medium devsel, latency 64, IRQ 20
 Memory at d0401000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=2K]
 Capabilities: [dc] Power Management version 2
 Kernel driver in use: firewire_ohci
 Kernel modules: firewire_ohci

44:06.1 SD Host controller: Ricoh Co Ltd R5C822 SD/SDIO/MMC/MS/MSPro Host Adapter (rev 25)
 Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company R5C822 SD/SDIO/MMC/MS/MSPro Host Adapter
 Flags: bus master, medium devsel, latency 64, IRQ 22
 Memory at d0403000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=256]
 Capabilities: [80] Power Management version 2
 Kernel driver in use: sdhci-pci
 Kernel modules: sdhci_pci

44:06.2 CardBus bridge: Ricoh Co Ltd RL5c476 II (rev bb)
 Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company RL5c476 II
 Flags: bus master, medium devsel, latency 168, IRQ 22
 Memory at d0400000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=4K]
 Bus: primary=44, secondary=45, subordinate=45, sec-latency=176
 Memory window 0: d8000000-dbffffff (prefetchable)
 Memory window 1: dc000000-dfffffff
 I/O window 0: 00002000-000020ff
 I/O window 1: 00002400-000024ff
 16-bit legacy interface ports at 0001
 Capabilities: [dc] Power Management version 2
 Kernel driver in use: yenta_cardbus
 Kernel modules: yenta_socket

ff:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Core Processor QuickPath Architecture Generic Non-core Registers (rev 02)
 Subsystem: Intel Corporation Core Processor QuickPath Architecture Generic Non-core Registers
 Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0

ff:00.1 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Core Processor QuickPath Architecture System Address Decoder (rev 02)
 Subsystem: Intel Corporation Core Processor QuickPath Architecture System Address Decoder
 Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0

ff:02.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Core Processor QPI Link 0 (rev 02)
 Subsystem: Intel Corporation Core Processor QPI Link 0
 Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0

ff:02.1 Host bridge: Intel Corporation 1st Generation Core i3/5/7 Processor QPI Physical 0 (rev 02)
 Subsystem: Intel Corporation 1st Generation Core i3/5/7 Processor QPI Physical 0
 Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0

ff:02.2 Host bridge: Intel Corporation 1st Generation Core i3/5/7 Processor Reserved (rev 02)
 Subsystem: Intel Corporation 1st Generation Core i3/5/7 Processor Reserved
 Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0

ff:02.3 Host bridge: Intel Corporation 1st Generation Core i3/5/7 Processor Reserved (rev 02)
 Subsystem: Intel Corporation 1st Generation Core i3/5/7 Processor Reserved
 Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0

jerry@hp-2540p:~$

jerry@hp-2540p:~$ sudo lshw -c video
[sudo] password for jerry:
  *-display
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: Core Processor Integrated Graphics Controller
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 2
       bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
       version: 02
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: msi pm vga_controller bus_master cap_list
       configuration: driver=i915 latency=0
       resources: irq:29 memory:d0000000-d03fffff memory:c0000000-cfffffff ioport:5058(size=8) memory:c0000-dffff

jerry@hp-2540p:~$ xrandr --verbose
Screen 0: minimum 16 x 16, current 2646 x 800, maximum 32767 x 32767
XWAYLAND0 connected 1280x800+0+0 (0x543) normal (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 260mm x 160mm
 Identifier: 0x21
 Timestamp: 110906
 Subpixel: unknown
 Gamma: 1.0:1.0:1.0
 Brightness: 0.0
 Clones:
 CRTC: 0
 CRTCs: 0
 Transform: 1.000000 0.000000 0.000000
             0.000000 1.000000 0.000000
             0.000000 0.000000 1.000000
            filter:
 non-desktop: 0
  supported: 0, 1
  1280x800 (0x543) 83.750MHz -HSync +VSync *current +preferred
        h: width 1280 start 1352 end 1480 total 1680 skew 0 clock 49.85KHz
        v: height 800 start 803 end 809 total 831 clock 59.99Hz
XWAYLAND1 connected 1366x768+1280+0 (0x546) normal (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 410mm x 230mm
 Identifier: 0x545
 Timestamp: 110906
 Subpixel: unknown
 Gamma: 1.0:1.0:1.0
 Brightness: 0.0
 Clones:
 CRTC: 1
 CRTCs: 1
 Transform: 1.000000 0.000000 0.000000
             0.000000 1.000000 0.000000
             0.000000 0.000000 1.000000
            filter:
 non-desktop: 0
  supported: 0, 1
  1366x768 (0x546) 84.500MHz -HSync +VSync *current +preferred
        h: width 1366 start 1431 end 1567 total 1776 skew 0 clock 47.58KHz
        v: height 768 start 771 end 781 total 798 clock 59.62Hz

jerry@hp-2540p:~$
```

Still confuse on how to fix this :

Bug #1971075
External monitor vga port with internal intel graphic not working with ubuntu 20.04 wayland

Anyone?

Thank you for your attention.

Comment: All that extra page after page of info makes a hard to read question.  From your question "Bug #1971075 External monitor vga port with internal intel graphic not working with ubuntu 20.04 wayland" Where can I see this bug report? Please remove anything not related to video.

Comment: Oops soory, I've already asked question within launchpad.net https://answers.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+question/703371

Comment: Have you tried the supported Ubuntu 20.04 5.15 kernel? instead of your used *testing* kernel?  The current *supported* kernel is https://packages.ubuntu.com/focal-updates/linux-generic-hwe-20.04 but looking at your [question](https://answers.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+question/703371); you added the *testing* PPA & installed the kernel there, instead of using the *supported* kernel ([*currently that would be*](https://packages.ubuntu.com/focal-updates/linux-generic-hwe-20.04) but you took on upgrading yourself manually it appears to me instead of using *supported* kernels)

Comment: Yes I did.  /usr/share/doc/linux-generic-hwe-20.04, Installed version: 5.15.0.48.54~20.04.18

Comment: Please update your question then with a fully updated system, your paste on this question shows a *rather* outdated system with many security fixes & patches not applied; which fits the initial bug report & answers.launchpad.net initial question, but not now (ie. October 2022).

Comment: I just don't get it... what do you mean with Update my question?

Comment: Your `hostname` details contain many details that need upgrading, eg. the kernel shows a *unsupported* or *testing* kernel which has not been updated in a long time, and that's only example (ie. not the only item).

Comment: jerry@hp-2540p:~$ cat /proc/version
Linux version 5.15.0-48-generic (buildd@lcy02-amd64-043) (gcc (Ubuntu 9.4.0-1ubuntu1~20.04.1) 9.4.0, GNU ld (GNU Binutils for Ubuntu) 2.34) #54~20.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Thu Sep 1 16:17:26 UTC 2022
jerry@hp-2540p:~$

Comment: jerry@hp-2540p:~$ hostnamectl
   Static hostname: hp-2540p
         Icon name: computer-laptop
           Chassis: laptop
        Machine ID: de4b56ef6180e8fc7e641c9d5fddb479
           Boot ID: 96bea95ad73a4c5aa74147b49e341884
  Operating System: Ubuntu 20.04.5 LTS
            Kernel: Linux 5.15.0-48-generic
      Architecture: x86-64

jerry@hp-2540p:~$ echo $XDG_SESSION_TYPE
wayland

Comment: Please update your question (that is what is answered on this site; and it shows an non-updated system using outdated/testing kernel), comments are for people to ask you (the Original Poster) question, once comments are addressed they'll be deleted, as the question itself is what is answered. This isn't a forum, but a Q&A site.